# Dynamically generating pzPVStream from a view

Tags: pega

Is there some way to create a view that returns a pzPVStream that can be natively parsed by Pega when it executes an RDB?

For instance, maybe a query (in MS SQL Server) that resembled:

```
SELECT test_tbl_outer.ID, (
    select *, 'My-Int-TestClass' as "pxObjClass"
    from {class:My-Int-TestClass} as test_tbl_inner
    where test_tbl_inner.ID=test_tbl_outer.ID
    FOR XML RAW('pagedata'), TYPE, ELEMENTS
) as pzPVStream
from {class:My-Int-TestClass} as test_tbl_outer
```

This gets an invalid signature error (the SQL query does work directly however), and if I try to shove a signature string onto the column ('PR6d' or previous) I just get a different error regarding headers.

So at this point, I do realize that the pzPVstream is not stored as xml but as some sort of packed & compressed string.  Is there a way for me to create a valid pzPVstream on the fly?  Maybe something similar to what pr_read_from_stream does but in reverse?

The use case is that we'd like to pull a whole mess of data from an existing data warehouse.  And it would be nice if we could pull all the multi-value data (many,many joins deep) over in one trip.  We are not too concerned with the size of this object as we plan on pulling this data one way or another.

Answer (score 3):

The pzPvStream is a compressed blob and it resonates a work object. It is compressed and stored as a single column in a table.

When it is read using obj-browse or obj-open activities, the blob is decompressed and all the encompassed properties are mapped to the clipboard.

This value has a proprietary format; the values are obfuscated.